# Change Keyboard Shortcuts in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora

The Dvorak keyboard option on Fedora 20 XFCE does not have an option to switch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, etc. shortcuts to where they are in QWERTY (which are very convenient locations).

So I would like to know how to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> to <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> to <kbd>Q</kbd>, and <kbd>Z</kbd> to <kbd>;</kbd>.
(On second thought, could I make it such that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> temporarily switches the layout to QWERTY?)

I have successfully switched <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to be where <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> was with xmodmap.  It'd be nice if I could use xmodmap for this, too.

**EDIT** 
I have found `setxkbmap -layout 'us,us' -variant 'dvorak,' -option 'grp:rctrl_switch' &` to be of use, however it requires the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> to be pressed to change the layout to QWERTY, and then the <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> to copy, for example. This system uses both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys to do commands; I'd like to acheive such with just one.